# Resemblance Between Turkish Ablative and Locative, Ancient Greek Ablative, Allative

Tags: historical-linguistics, greek, turkish

I was studying some Ancient Greek, and found out that the declination of some irregular nouns are very similar.

I started wondering if there is actually a language that is mother of Altaic languages and Indo-European languages that we can partially reconstruct by finding other languages that have this feature, or these are just some borrowed words as a result of some peculiar ancient migration.

Is there another Indo-European language that has this "-den", "-de" postfixes for declensions of nouns?

Turkish:
Ev (house)
Ev-den (from house)
Ev-de (in house)

Ancient Greek:
οἴκα (house)
οἴκο-θεν (from house)
οἴκα-δε (towards house)

Comment: a) cp *town*? *den*? *London*? b) cp *than, then*, *so then go home*, *I will go home then [now]* c) Ger fig. *unten* "the valley" (*unter* ~ *under*), *oben*, etc, a few weird semantic shifts like above > below, but the *-n* is quite ubiquitious and regular d) likewise *Norden, Süden, Osten, Westen*, *Gestern*, significant symbolism, analogical leveling from \*-trom, \*traz?

Comment: e) Sumerian *E* "house, temple", the first google hit gives: "the landlord of a pub is written as lú, determinative for a profession, followed by é, determinative for a house, followed by the logogram kash for `beer'.", I doubt it meant precisely *beer*, sounds funny though f) Incidently, Ger *Ökonomie* (oikos + ...; modern coinage?) is synonymous with *Wirtschaft* "economy", also "establishment; pub, restaurant", perhaps comparable to En *worship*, Ger *Wertschöpfung* "value creation" and then it get's dark; if *oikos* reflect \*weyk-, whence OHG *wih*, En *wick, wich*, cp *Rat*, \*wih-rat*?

Comment: g) Garden *Eden* ... h) Ger arch. *Arbeiter Kotten* "worker house, ie. no stables and such" or should that be *[house of servants] of the house*?

Comment: Re: b) As for comparative *than* (equiv. Ger arch. *denn*), cp "[As others have said, in Greek the true ablative collapsed with the genitive. Hence the use of the genitive **in comparisons** ("greater starting from ...) and with 'from' words.](https://www.reddit.com/r/AncientGreek/comments/9spyve/comment/e8qnomu)". i) There's also Ger *dannen* "away", now chiefly in *von dannen ziehen* "to go away, retreat", attested since 9th century OHG ("fona thanan"). j) wiki/ablative has western Armenian *dun* "house", *danen* "from the house" (east. *tun* ~ *tnic'*), Finnish *-ta* ~ *-tä*, Hungr. *-tol*.

Comment: Re: i) compare *dahin* "to there", also "away, broken, dead", *hin und her* "to and fro"; cp perhaps En *yon-, yonder*. j) Anatolian also had ablative, what does that look like? What about Etruscan? I'm sorry for the spam, so sorry.

Comment: yeah actually, Turkish also uses ablative for comparative like
"Ev-den daha pahalı" (ev: house, daha: comparative word, pahalı: expensive), "It is more expensive comparing to a house". I wonder if that's a coincidence or it might help us find the link?

Comment: for sumer'an "lú", i know it is getting away from the subject but i can give a side note, in Turkish there is "-li", meaning "with, has". The sultan would be called "devlet-lü" (old form is -lü) as an adjective, meaning "having state".
It has two uses, one of them is for where you are from. Like "Ankara-lı" (declines with last wovel and becomes "lı"). The other use for denoting "with", like "Çatal-lı yol" (çatal: fork, yol: road, the road with fork, seperating road),
mot-a-mot translation of the sumerian word you are talking about, "ev-li", would mean "married", "having a house".

Comment: yonder is very interesting. Turkish yön means direction, "o yön-de" (o: that, it) means "in that direction".

Comment: Brosch suggests a directive adverbial particle \*o "zu" (viz *to*) in order to explain *pro* and the like, cf [Untersuchungen zur hethitischen Raumgrammatik. p. 330]. Awesome! However, one word of advise: We evidently get fewer and fewer languages as time goes on, consequently, I would always posit more languages for the past. That is, a single "mother language" is obviously highly unrealistic for prehistory. The only constant in this view is change, so to speak, or rather *exchange*.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, οἴκα-δε seems to have an [IE pedigree](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/de) as a postpositional demonstrative "towards". However, Ringe "The Accent of Adverbs in -θεν: A Historical Analysis" (Glossa 1977) discussed the origin of this item in Greek, noting that it is not from Indo-European (citing Lejeune, *Les Adverbes grecs en -θεν* for "exhaustive discussion"). Ringe notes that it is not clearly attested in Mycenaean.

Comment: Where does Ringe (or Lejeune) say it comes from if it's not IE? Is there phonological evidence for it being pre-Greek or something like that?

Comment: Are you contrasting -de with -then, or giving two separate opinions for each of them? At least according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0e), -then is also derived from PIE

Comment: The opinions regarding the two cases differ, which I'm reporting. I did not know of that Wiki page for θɛν ← dʰe and can't proffer an opinion of the merits of Ringe / Lejeun vs. Wiki. Might be able to get pages from Lejeune in a week.

Comment: Wiki references Georg E. Dunkel, *Lexikon der Indogermanischen Partikeln und Pronomina, 2014. The same reference is made by Cyril Brosch in *Untersuchungen zur hethitischen Raumgrammatik*, who further references Dunkel 1997. So the ref is legit, I wasn't sure. Brosch's bibliography is not in G-books, Dunkel is a terribly difficult to search name, and I can't find it in G-scholar either. At least other parts of the book are accessible: once submitting Hitt. *appan* "hinter, hinten", from an ablative-instrumental \*-om (p.p. 356) also ...

Comment: but explicitly not so for *kattan* "unter, unten" nor *andan* "in, (dr)innen". On p. 419 They also note that some "Formantien" can be seen as postpositions, like "direktivisches \*=de", that recharacterized direction-accusatives in Greek (cp Dunkel 2007: 335-339), and by the way that \*-d(h)i were locative, \*-ti, \*-tos ablative; the treat three different kinds of abl. in ch. 2. etc etc. All the detail and uncertainty at the same time is staggering.